# Porting Windows Phone 8 app to Android

Tags: c#, java, android, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to port my app (http://goo.gl/I1TsKV), to android from Windows phone 8.

It's programmed using C# and XAML and I was wondering if there's a way to port it without having to write it all over again on android.

Kind Regards,
Erik

(Please don't fly loose on me if this isn't enough to be a programming question, but I just don't know where to ask elsewhere)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487853/how-to-port-a-windows-phone-7-app-to-android?rq=1

Comment: This is probably not the right forum for this type question (not flying off, just stating my opinion softly), but I'd say no, there are not any tools to magically convert a C# app to Java.  However, there is a tool called PhoneGap (actually, I think the project is Apache Cordova, PhoneGap is just one offering of it) that allows you to write your app in HTML5, then generate clients for many mobile platforms.  If you have to rewrite it anyways, and you think you might want to support iOS, Blackberry, etc then it may be worth a look.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Xamarin. It will allow you to reuse your C# business logic, but you'll still have to rewrite your UI code. http://xamarin.com/

Comment: I've looked at it once before, can I use SharedPreferences the same way as I do with java on android? The app uses a LOT of saving strings - so having a good storage is a must